# How to left align subfigure caption

Tags: subfloats, alignment

How can I get my subfigure caption to be left aligned? I have a minimum demonstration shown below with an example of how the figure turns out. I have tried setting the raggedright and check single line option to false for the caption and can't seem to get anything to work. Does anyone know how to get it to work with this example?

```
\documentclass{cas-dc}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{thumbnails/cas-twitter.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{thumbnails/cas-facebook.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{How do I left align this caption? Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscingelit. Duis tellus. Donec ante dolor, iaculis nec, gravidaac, cursus in, eros. Mauris vestibulum, felis et egestasullamcorper, purus nibh vehicula sem, eu egestas antenisl non justo. Fusce tincidunt, lorem nev dapibusconsectetuer, leo orci mollis ipsum, eget suscipit erospurus in ante. At ipsum vitae est lacinia tincidunt. Maecenas elit orci,gravida ut, molestie non, venenatis vel, lorem. Sedlacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Sed ultricies cursuslectus. }
    \label{fig:asdf}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: (a) None of the `\centering` instructions does anything useful; omit them. (b) The `subcaption` environment doesn't recognize a `h` option. (c) you should insert `\hfill` bertween the two `subfigure` environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
This document class (`cas-dc`) expect that \begin{figure*} doesn't follow float position position, for example `[ht]` but rather `[width=\textwidth]` or simple nothing or combination

```
\begin{figure*}[width=\textwidth, ht]
```

or in case of one columns text (as seems to be in your case) simple

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
```

It is not entirely clear, if you like to have two column document - in this case a possible solution is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{cas-dc} % had to be added option `twocolumn`
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{natbib} % had to be loaded
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[width=\textwidth, ht] % <---
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{thumbnails/cas-twitter.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{thumbnails/cas-facebook.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\lipsum[66]}
    \label{fig:asdf}
\end{figure*} 

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

or one column document using `cas-dc` document class, where the solution is

```
\documentclass{cas-dc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{natbib} % had to be loaded
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\begin{figure}[ht] % <---
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{thumbnails/cas-twitter.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{thumbnails/cas-facebook.jpeg}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\lipsum[66]}
    \label{fig:asdf}
\end{figure} % <---

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that you like to have left align subfigure caption, like

[image]

then you only need to load `subcaption` package as:

```
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{subcaption}
```

Comment: Thank you, this perfectly answered my question and solved my problem.